# Imgur API: Is there a way to pre-name an image to be uploaded later?

Tags: imgur

I'm writing some image upload code in a constrained environment. The host OS won't let me wait around for the image to finish uploading, although it will let me start the upload. But I want to be able to produce the URL that the image will eventually have immediately.

Is there any Imgur API that lets me pre-flight an image upload and get its URL or ID, and then later upload the actual image content for that name or ID?